# Can't Call OnItemClicklistner (with reference of checkBox in View parameter) on clicking on checkbox in Custom ListView

Tags: checkbox, android-listview, onitemclicklistener, clickable, focusable

I am unable to fire OnItemClicklistner method on clicking on Checkbox (in my List-view), i have tried following way...

i have set the focusability and clickability to false as follows.

```
android:focusable="false"
android:clickable="false"
android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
```

It fires the OnItemClicklistner but doesn't send reference of Checkbox in view parameter. Please help on this.

Comment: You need to show, at least, the relevant code like ListView, Adapter, and/or Listeners. In this case, the Layout file may be helpful too.

Comment: Why set :clickable="false", I would remove it. Checkbox does not have OnItemClickListener. I'll post an answer just for this one.

Answer (score 0):

Please look at Google documentation at [CheckBox class](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CheckBox.html).
Checkbox does not have OnItemClicklistener. You may be getting events from a different UI element, hence confusing you. Checkbox has `setOnClickListener` method for you to use. Remember documentation is there to help you.